# Why the lombok @Builder can't be used with @NoArgsConstructor togerther?

Tags: lombok

the exception is shown following:

```
@Builder
^
  required: no arguments
  found: String,String,String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

the deep reasons behind the phenomenon.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Javadoc say this :

> lombok will assume an all-args constructor is present and generate
> code that uses it; this means you'd get a compiler error if this
> constructor is not present

cf. https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.projectlombok/lombok/latest/lombok/Builder.html

So if you want to use `@NoArgsConstructor`, add also the annotation `@AllArgsConstructor`. Example :

```
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
class Example {
    private String a;
    private String b;
}
```